# Errors when using buildozer to compile kivy/python 3.7 app into android apk on OSX - Silex & pypandoc

Tags: android, macos, kivy, apk, buildozer

I've made an app using kivy and python 3.7, on OSX. It runs quite well within the PyCharm environment. However, buildozer keeps throwing up errors when I try to compile the app with buildozer.

I have installed the latest buildozer using the pip3.7 command. I have even updated python-for-android to test it out. I am also currently using the Android NDK r19c, although I have tried it with r17c and r20. Neither have worked.

Originally, I had errors relating to the use of pip, instead of pip3.7, since buildozer would try to use python 2.7 in some areas. This was solved by uninstalling buildozer etc. and reinstalling with pip3.7. Those errors have gone but at the moment, I seem to be getting new errors, related to 'Silex' and pypandoc, which is strange since I don't believe buildozer even uses those.

The error codes have too many characters to allow me to post them directly here, so please see the error codes as a page on my website. The links are below:

https://apilotslens.com/buildozer-silex-error

I then install the most recent version of Silex, which stops this error coming. However, a new error comes, relating to pypandoc:

https://apilotslens.com/buildozer-pypandoc-error

Even when I install pypandoc, the error keeps appearing.

I am very confused at this point. I have supposedly done everything by the book, so that buildozer will compile my APK. I really hope someone can help me. As far as I am aware, Buildozer doesn't even use Silex or pypandoc, so why would they be appearing? They haven't even been mentioned before. I really want to get this sorted soon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is very weird, could you paste the contents of the file Users/JGolding/Desktop/FlightPlanningApp/PythonCode/Drafts/Draft1/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py ?

Comment: Sure. I'm on a work computer at the moment but as soon as I'm home, I will post it on here and I'll let you know. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Actually, line 80 that the error points out *should* be `import shlex`. If you haven't touched this file manually, I guess maybe it could have been corrupted somehow, but I don't really know how that would have happened. Have you tried cleaning the build and letting the download run again? You can do that by deleting `/Users/JGolding/Desktop/FlightPlanningApp/PythonCode/Drafts/Draft1/.buildozer`, i.e. the .buildozer directory in your app dir.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I haven't touched the file manually at all. The only thing I have tried is a clean: ``buildozer android clean`` but that hasn't got it working. I'll try it by deleting the file and letting the download run again. You never know. It certainly is an unusal error to have. I'm guessing I shouldn't be touching the ``import shlex`` area of the file at all myself?

Comment: Wait, do you mean shlex or silex?

Comment: Here's the link to the ``toolchain.py`` file you mentioned: https://apilotslens.com/buildozer-toolchain-py . it's just completely broken at the moment though. Whether I run ``buildozer android debug`` or ``buildozer android clean`` (basically any buildozer command) the ``silex`` error instantly appears. I really don't know what is happening...

Comment: I thought I'd try uninstalling and reinstalling buildozer (``pip3.7 uninstall buildozer``) but interestingly, it says ``Can't uninstall 'buildozer'. No files were found to uninstall.`` However, when I try to install it with a similar command, it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied. It's very strange. There's seemingly nothing to install or uninstall...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm pretty sure I haven't touched the file manually at all. The only thing I have tried is a clean: buildozer android clean but that hasn't got it working.

This only cleans the build, not the full cache. Delete `/Users/JGolding/Desktop/FlightPlanningApp/PythonCode/Drafts/Draft1/.buildozer` and try again.

> Wait, do you mean shlex or silex?

It *should* read `import shlex`. Your file reads `import silex`.

> Here's the link to the toolchain.py file you mentioned:

This looks good except for the shlex->silex change.

> I thought I'd try uninstalling and reinstalling buildozer (pip3.7 uninstall buildozer) but interestingly, it says Can't uninstall 'buildozer'. No files were found to uninstall.

This is something unrelated arising from your pip invocation targeting the wrong directory or something.

> I then install the most recent version of Silex, which stops this error coming. However, a new error comes, relating to pypandoc:

This is also unrelated, it's just that the silex module doesn't support python 3. The silex module was always a red herring, it's just the letter switch in your copy of toolchain.py that is wrong.

Note that if you read the error, it isn't complaining about pypandoc but about `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response. Changing ``silex`` to ``shlex`` in the ``toolchain.py`` file solved that weird ``silex`` issue. i'm now back to an older error: ``[ERROR]:   Build failed: Couldn't find executable for CC. This indicates a problem locating the arm-linux-androideabi-gcc executable in the Android NDK, not that you don't have a normal compiler installed. Exiting.`` How do I get round this?

Comment: I've seen one forum post where they said "You can't build android version with latest ndk ,such as ndk 19c , Because the latest ndk compiler has changed from gcc to clang . I build successful the android version with ndk r14b" I tried using an older version but it doesn't work, since the minimum NDK version is 17. Have you heard of this error before?

Comment: Use NDK 17c with the current p4a release, or ndk 20 with the current p4a master.

Comment: I tried all that and I just keep getting the same age-old errors I've always had. For example, for the NDK 17c/p4a current release combination, this is the output: apilotslens.com/buildozer-errors-with-p4a-release-2019-8-9 . For the NDK 20/development release combination, this is the output: buildozer-errors-with-p4a-master .

Comment: The latter one (NDK 20 / p4a master) does reduce the error output code significantly but just like the other one, it comes up with the error: ``[ERROR]:   Build failed: Couldn't find executable for CC. This indicates a problem locating the arm-linux-androideabi-gcc executable in the Android NDK, not that you don't have a normal compiler installed. Exiting.`` Both of them, much earlier in the run, give a warning still: ``[WARNING]: Cython for python3 missing. If you are building for  a python 3 target (which is the default) then THINGS WILL BREAK.`` Is this part of the issue? How do I solve it?

Comment: It's worth noting that I have already installed Cython, using ``pip3.7 install cython``, hence why I am unsure as to why it doesn't think cython is installed.

Comment: The NDK 20 error indicates that you probably aren't using python-for-android master. The cython thing is just a warning, it doesn't matter.

Comment: i did check which version I had installed though, using ``p4a --version``. The terminal outputs ``2019.08.09.1.dev0`` which I believe is the master branch. Is it possible that buildozer is still trying to use something else, instead of the master branch? I'm happy that the Cython warning doesn't really matter at least. What would be best to try next, to get round the NDK 20 error?

Comment: Did you tell buildozer to use the version you have installed separately?

Comment: Well I instructed it to use the NDK version 20. I didn't give a specific version instruction for the p4a version, since it said it just defaults to master if you don't give it a specific one. I can try this later and let you know

Comment: My mistake, I should have said you need to use python-for-android's *develop* branch for NDK 20 support.

Comment: Ah right I see. Thanks for clarifying. It looks like I had actually installed the development version in any case. I used this command: ``pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git``. The only thing I have missed from what you have said is to not specify the development branch in the ``buildozer.spec`` file. I left it with the # in, so it would default to the master instead. Can I presume the master and development are different then? I'll let  you know what happens when I try it now.

Comment: I ran it with the ``develop`` branch and that error didn't appear thankfully. Now, it gets to the point where it says the first attempt will fail and then it quits again. Here's the error code (thankfully not too long now): https://apilotslens.com/buildozer-errors-after-first-build-failed . Any ideas?

Comment: The error suggests you don't have cython installed for python3.

Comment: I tried again yesterday to install it with pip3.7, as I have done with p4a etc. It kept telling me the requirement is already satisfied, so it seems it is installed for python3. I'll try again later, just incase.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. It looks like, where the error appears, it's trying to find Cython using a different version of Python in the apple python.framework file. That's Python 3.5. At the start of the error script I posted, it does say it has found Cython and gives the location. When I use ``cython --version`` I get the most up to date cython for python 3.7, so I'm sure I have the right one installed.

Comment: I haven't tried that. What does that command do? I'll give it a go later and I'll let you know

Comment: So I have downloaded miniconda3 and installed cython that way. After that, there is no longer an error relating to cython not being found. Your command, ``python3 -m cython`` now comes up with full details for cython. The ``buildozer android debug`` command now runs for over 4 mins but has come up with different errors. For what went wrong, it says ``Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.`` What does that mean?

Comment: Post the full log again. But, I can at least note that this is the final stage in the build process to actually pack the APK, the compiling is working now.

Comment: Of course, I should have done that earlier. It is here: apilotslens.com/buildozer-error-missing-name-key-attribute-sdk . Thanks. I'm glad to hear it is nearly there now!

Comment: This indicates issues with the AndroidManifest.xml that has been autogenerated. I don't know how, but given your earlier issue was an inexplicable character corruption I guess anything's possible. Could you clean the build (delete the .buildozer file in your app dir) and run it again just to make sure everything is from scratch, then if the issue recurs post the content of /Users/JGolding/Desktop/FlightPlanningApp/PythonCode/Drafts/Draft1/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/flightappv01/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I see. It's quite funny how many different errors have had. I'll try to do that a bit later then and I'll let you know. If it doesn't work, I'll post the contents of the file. Initially, all I was doing was ``buildozer android clean`` before trying again, which obvously hasn't worked. I noticed though that when you look for the ``.buildozer`` file manually (i.e. go to users, then my username, then desktop) the file is nowhere to be seen, but when you search directly with the file path, it exists. How come that is?

Comment: `buildozer android clean` only deletes certain components of the build, there isn't a command to delete all of them (but there will be in the next buildozer release)

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're looking for the folder in a file manager that has 'show hidden files' disabled. The initial . makes it hidden.

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for that next buildozer release then. Thanks for explaining the hidden file attribute to me. I really appreciate your help so far. I'll go ahead and delete the file later, re-run it and let you know if it has worked.

Comment: So I've just re-run it having deleted the ``.buildozer`` file. It failed again. Here's the error transcript: apilotslens.com/buildozer-error-after-build . The error doesn't seem to be similar to that one before, related to AndroidManifest. However, here's the file you asked for anyway: apilotslens.com/buildozer-androidmanifest . Maybe it'll give you some clues. I'm hoping I'm nearly there now, although this time it didn't even get to the debugging phase...

Comment: I've just looked at the error after build transcript in the link I gave you and I noticed that the distribution seems to have been created successfully ``[INFO]:    # Your distribution was created successfully, exiting.`` . It then says the distribution can be found (for now) at... but then when it goes on to build the application ``# Build the application #1`` this is when it fails. What is the issue there?